# Use Barcode Scanner + with intent from Xamarin Android app

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

I'm developing an app (for a single customer) with Xamarin that must read barcodes with the camera (and optionally with an external bluetooth scanner), and used for testing an Asus TF300T, a LG4xP880 and a Nexus 7 second edition (the target machine).

I tested ScandIt and ZXing, but the best results I had with the free Barcode Scanner app (same library of ZXing, I know, but can't get the same speed).
I've read that I can use it with an intent, and I can also buy the plus version (need portrait scanning), but I couldn't find any documentation on how to (if possible), with intent call only:

- configure the layout, select portrait/landscape
- select the barcode type (exclude some)
- insert a button that exits scanning without reading

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

ZXing provides an IntentIntegrator class that either launches ZXing or prompts the user to install it from the Google Play store. However, if you know Barcode Scanner or Barcode Scanner Plus is installed, you can just call `StartActivityForResult` yourself. Here is a [recipe using StartActivityForResult](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/files/selecting_a_gallery_image/)

The layout is determined by the orientation of the device, there is no need to specify it. However, as you are aware, ZXing only works in landscape, so you will need to buy the plus version for portrait support.

ZXing provides two options for specifying the barcodes to decode

```
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", ...)
```

According to [ZXing Intents](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/Intents.java) scan mode can be one of `PRODUCT_MODE`, `ONE_D_MODE`, `QR_CODE_MODE` or `DATA_MATRIX_MODE`. Alternatively you can provide a list of formats you'd like to support for any given instance

```
intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "EAN_13,EAN_8,QR_CODE,...")
```

The plus version was published by Sean Owen of the ZXing team and it based on ZXing, so it probably has identical configuration options and responds to the same intent.

**Bonus:** I wrote an [app for external scanners](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nomadlabs.ojai) that does the heavy lifting of connecting and configuring the scanner. It makes it trivial to add bluetooth barcode scanner support to any new or existing app. Think of it as ZXing for bluetooth barcode scanning. The [client code](https://github.com/nomad-labs/OjaiClient) is up on GitHub and provides instructions for getting started.

Comment: Thank you for all the useful information.
Tomorrow I'll but Scanner+ and test with the intents.

Comment: My only need then would be to use a custom layout, and I wonder if is possible: essential would be to add a big "Cancel" button to return to my app without reading the barcode. 
The user wont't have available the back/menu/home buttons (still have to figure out how) because the tablet will use only this app.

Thanks for the suggestion, but we excluded external scanner because the user has only one hand free to operate.